# How to expand a Hash of Arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I don't know if "expand" is the right word, but here is what I would like to do =)

This script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; 
use strict;

my %HoA = (
    group1 => [ "user1", "user2" ],
    group2 => [ "group1", "user3" ],
    group3 => [ "group1", "group2" ],
    group4 => [ "group3", "user2" ],
    );

foreach my $group ( keys %HoA ) {
    print "$group: @{ $HoA{$group} }\n"
}
```

outputs

```
group1: user1 user2
group2: group1 user3
group3: group1 group2
group4: group3 user4
```

What I would like is to replace the groups in the array with the members. I.e. so the output and `$HoA` becomes

```
group1: user1 user2
group2: user1 user2 user3
group3: user1 user2 user3
group4: user1 user2 user3 user4
```

Perhaps "search and replace" and remove duplicates would be a better explanation of what I would like to do?

Comment: What if you have circular references? i.e what if group1 has group2, and group2 has group1?

Comment: Then I would like to ship that group, and print an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data you have given, the following loop will create a new hash with the expanded arrays.  This algorithm assumes that groups will resolve in sorted order (group2 will only depend on group1, group3 on 1 / 2, ...).

```
my %expanded;
for my $group (sort keys %HoA) {
    my %seen;
    $expanded{$group} = [
        grep {not $seen{$_}++}
        map {exists $expanded{$_} ? @{$expanded{$_}} : $_}
        @{$HoA{$group}}
    ];
    print "$group: @{ $expanded{$group} }\n"
}
```

which prints:

```
group1: user1 user2
group2: user1 user2 user3
group3: user1 user2 user3
group4: user1 user2 user3
```

If you can not assume a resolution order, the following is a bit brute force, but should work:

```
my %HoA = (
    group1 => [ "user1", "user2" ],
    group2 => [ "group1", "user3" ],
    group3 => [ "group1", "group2" ],
    group4 => [ "user5", "group5" ],
    group5 => [ "group3", "user2" ],
    );

my @to_expand = keys %HoA;

my %final;
my $tries = @to_expand;
to_expand: while (@to_expand and $tries) {
    my $next = shift @to_expand;

    my (@users, @groups);
    for (@{ $HoA{$next} }) {
        if (/^group/) {
            push @groups, $_;
        } else {
            push @users, $_;
        }
    }
    for my $group (@groups) {
        if (exists $final{$group}) {
            push @users, @{$final{$group}}
        } else {
            $tries--;
            push @to_expand, $next;
            next to_expand;
        }
    }
    $tries++;
    my %seen;
    $final{$next} = [grep {not $seen{$_}++} @users];
}
if (@to_expand) {
    print "error with groups: @to_expand\n";
}

for (sort keys %final) {
    print "$_: @{$final{$_}}\n";
}
```

which prints:

```
group1: user1 user2
group2: user3 user1 user2
group3: user1 user2 user3
group4: user5 user2 user1 user3
group5: user2 user1 user3
```

if there is an error (say group3 depends on group5), then you will get this output:

```
error with groups: group4 group5 group3
group1: user1 user2
group2: user3 user1 user2
```

There's probably a better algorithm out there for this.

Comment: I sadly can't make that assumption =( The groups can include each other in any combination. Very impressive script none the less!

Comment: I understand what's going on until `for my $group (@groups) {`. Can you explain what `$tries` is used for? And how `%seen` works?

Comment: @Sandra => `$tries` is a counter similar to `$cont` in leonbloy's answer and `$deep` in Axeman's.  It is there to prevent these algorithms from going into an infinite loop (or deep recursion) when faced with circular or otherwise unresolvable dependency.  The idea behind `%seen` is to keep an `O(1)` lookup table of already added users.  This table is consulted for each user, and if that user has not been seen, they are added to the final list.

Answer (score 3):

This will throw an error if there are recursions - not foolproof and not ver elegant, though

```
use strict;

my %HoA = (
    group1 => [ "user1", "user2" ],
    group2 => [ "group1", "user3" ],
    group3 => [ "group1", "group2" ],
    group4 => [ "group3", "user2" ],
    );

my %ex=(); # expanded hash

foreach my $g ( keys %HoA ) { # first population
     $ex{$g} = {};
     AddArrayToHash($ex{$g},$HoA{$g});
}
my $goon = 1;
my $cont =0;
while($goon) { # iterate
    $goon=0;
    die "too many iterations RECURSIVE DEFINITION?" if($cont++ >10) ;
    foreach my $g ( keys %ex ) {
        foreach my $u ( keys %{$ex{$g}} ) {
            if($ex{$u}) {
                delete $ex{$g}->{$u};
                AddArrayToHash($ex{$g},[ keys %{$ex{$u}}] );
                $goon = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach my $group ( sort keys %ex ) {
    print "$group: " . join(" ",sort  keys %{$ex{$group}}) ."\n";
}

sub AddArrayToHash {
    my($refhash,$refarray)=@_;
    foreach my $e (@$refarray) {
        $refhash->{$e} = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people had to write so much code:

```
sub expand_group { 
    my ( $ref, $arref, $deep ) = @_;
    croak 'Deep Recursion!' if ++$deep > scalar( keys %$ref );
    return map { 
        exists $ref->{$_} ? expand_group( $ref, $ref->{$_}, $deep ) : $_ 
    } @$arref
    ;
}

sub expand_groups { 
    my ( $block, $group_ref ) = @_;
    while ( my ( $key, $val ) = each %$group_ref ) {
        $block->( $key, expand_group( $group_ref, $val, 1 ));
    }
}

expand_groups( sub { say join( ' ', @_ ); }, \%HoA );
```

Comment: There's no need for the `&%` prototype unless you want to call it like `expand_groups { say join ' ', @_ } %HoA` .

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; 
use strict;

my %HoA = (
    group1 => [ "user1", "user2" ],
    group2 => [ "group1", "user3" ],
    group3 => [ "group1", "group2" ],
    group4 => [ "group3", "user2" ],
    );


my %users; 

foreach my $group ( sort keys %HoA ) {
  %users = ();

  print "$group: ";
  print_key($group, $HoA{$group});
  print join " ", sort keys %users;
  print "\n";
}

sub print_key {
  my $group = shift;

  foreach my $item (@{$HoA{$group}}) {
    if (exists $HoA{$item}) {
       print_key($item);
    }
    else {
       $users{$item}++;
    }
  }
}
```